# Controlling a circular magnetic field with microcontroller

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics

I have this idea for a project and I'm looking for some direction.  There is a "clock" in a recent tv show that I want to recreate.   See [this image](https://i.insider.com/5e6ed1f8235c187cc30a2fb2?width=700&format=jpeg&auto=webp) , or [This image](https://www.coffeeklatchcrew.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/WW_S3_E6.jpg)If you're familiar with Westworld you'll know it.

I started looking at magnetic sand and then at ferrofluid.  Ferrofluid seems to give the effect that I'm looking for but I have no idea where/what to even begin looking at.

To me I see a circular electromagnet, the field could be altered to give the desired affect with the ferrofluid.

So at stasis there would be a stable field and it would look like the first image.  It could dynamically shift to look similar to the second image.

My question is where do I start here?  Googling for "control circular magnetic field with arduino" didn't net me much.  Most were create a electromagnet with a relay etc.

Would I need to control one large field, multiple smaller ones?

I don't mean for this to be vague, as I said, I'm not sure where to even start here.  Maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: So do you want something similar to a compass but with magnetic sand?

Comment: Sort of. More like a sunspot.  Normally it would just be a ring but then I could control where on that ring I wanted activity.  See this video from .25 to .35.  That affect.  [Sunspot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsULoSebWnE)

Comment: Motor + permanent magnet?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany would that give the resolution he wants? maybe it would resemble a bit the first picture, but it wouldn't help at all with the second one where you have many "tendrils" of different sizes that are individually controlled.

Comment: Resolution was one of the things I was curious about. Can I get any sort of detail with a single field. Maybe not detail , but detail and control?

Comment: With one coil in a non-magnetic environment you will get no spatial resolution at all, just control of intensity.

Comment: What if you had a stationary magnetic ring.  That would provide the base, ie the thin line.  Then you'd have a controllable magnet that could traverse that ring and its intensity changed.   I'll admit, I'm well out of my depth here, I know what I want to accomplish.

Comment: A coil generates the strongest magnetic field just near and inside the coil. To make a coil affect with its full force further away from the coil one needs an iron bar between the coil and the wanted strong field place. If you have a single large area coil you have NO way to limit a small spot where the coil actually affects. The effect covers the whole coil and its near neighbourhood. You must have a separate coil in every spot where you need local control and every coil needs its own control circuit.

Comment: (continued) You can use permanent magnets and have a hidden mechanism which moves 1...2 of those magnets. the effect is impressive as long as nobody notices the moving magnets. If the moving magnet is especially strong it can collect all of your magnetic material.

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me.  I want to avoid collecting material. So I'd want something strong enough to get the affect I want but not drag all the material around?  I need to order some materials. The example I looked at was a ferrofluid in what was most likely glycerin.   Thank you for the direction, I'll update with follow up questions most likely once I test some of this.

Comment: Ah I see you also watch Westworld!

Comment: @Leoman12  yep. As soon as I saw that/this thing I've been obsessing about it.  I think I have a working idea now thanks to this.

Comment: Just watch out for Dolores. She’s nuts.

Answer (score 1):

To get the ring shape, you will need to use a magnetic trap, the proof of concept of this would be to have 2 coils in the shape you want (the circle), spaced apart by about 1.4x how wide you want the circle to be.

To get the spikes, you will need magnetic traps aswell, though this time it can just be a single coil in the shape of the spikes, this likely means you will have to settle for radius out shapes for hands on the clock, you would turn on these coils in sequence to move the hands.

The amount of current you will need to run through the wires will also be fairly high, you can reduce it by having more turns, and likely will only work well while flat, in a vertical situation against gravity the control scheme would get quite difficult to make it a somewhat even thickness,

[image]
[Image Source](http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electricity%20and%20magnetism/Electromagnetism/text/Forces_between_currents/index.html)

To best explain the image, the ferrofluid will gather at the pole of a magnet, 2 coils with opposing current flow will make a consistent pole between them that is attracting it into that shape, you need 2 coils here as you want the entire ring shape,

This would be the point in the 2b diagram where all of the field lines are bunched up tightly,

For the hands as you just need the fluid trapped inside the profile of the coil, so a single coil can be used.

Comment: I was just going to ask what sort of amperage are we talking about here ?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with how easily it is to move ferrofluid, so start with thin wire coils, about 100 turns with half an amp, then trim from there?

Comment: Ok perfect, that gives me a starting point.